# pointer being freed was not allocated - How to debug?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, malloc

I am getting the runtime error

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x10070c5c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

with the following stack trace:

[image]

This tells me that something goes wrong in the destructors `~Clustering` and `~NodeMap` (the first one is an empty stub, the second one calls `delete[]`), but not which the "pointer being freed" is. How can I find this out?

Also, where is `malloc_error_break`?

Comment: Run it under valgrind or any such memory leak/corruption detection tool.

Comment: Read about the "[Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)."

Comment: "*This tells me that something goes wrong in the destructors `~Clustering` and `~NodeMap` (which are empty stubs)*". I don't think they are both empty. I'm pretty sure that that `~NodeMap()` calls `delete[]`.

Comment: @Robᵩ You're right, I corrected this in the question.

Comment: @cls what is it calling `delete[]` on?  It seems that that pointer isn't valid?  Was it initialized to `NULL` and/or set to `new[]`.

Comment: @JaredC on an array of `int64_t`. it was not set to `NULL` but allocated with `new T[n]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This tells me that something goes wrong in the destructors `~Clustering` and `~NodeMap` (the first one is an empty stub, the second one calls `delete[]`), but not which the "pointer being freed" is.

Just because `~Clustering` is "an empty stub" doesn't mean its doesn't do anything. After executing the body of the destructor, the destructor calls the destructors for each direct non-variant non-static data member. Apparently your class `Clustering` contains a data member of type `NodeMap<long,long>`.

> How can I find this out?

How many allocated arrays does your class `NodeMap<long,long>` contain? If it's only one, that's the one. If there are more than one, set a breakpoint in `~NodeMap` so you can step through the execution.

Comment: `Clustering` derives from `NodeMap`. The array is indeed the source of the error, and I believe I have to implement a correct copy constructor to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a copy constructor that copies allocated memory? If there isn't a copy constructor or if it is but doesn't copy allocated memory then destructors of two objects try to free the same memory locations.

Comment: I do not have a copy constructor. This seems to be the underlying problem.